# When adding something to linked list, the other items on the list take the name of the last item added

Tags: arrays, c, string, linked-list

I have a console application written in C, which takes inputs from the user in order to manipulate a linked list.

When the user inputs "add" to add an item, it will add the item, but all nodes added this way will share the name of the last item made using the "add" command.

**list.h**

```c
typedef struct node {
    char *name;
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node_js;

static node_js *currentNode;

void printList(node_js *thing) {
    currentNode = thing;

    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", currentNode->name);
        printf(">%d\n", currentNode->value);

        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void addLast(node_js **thing, const char *name, int val) {
    if (*thing == NULL) {
        *thing = (node_js *)malloc(sizeof(node_js));
        //(*thing)->name = name;
        (*thing)->name = name;
        (*thing)->value = val;
        (*thing)->next = NULL;
    } else {
        currentNode = *thing;

        while (currentNode->next != NULL) {
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }

        currentNode->next = (node_js *)malloc(sizeof(node_js));
        //currentNode->next->name = strdup(name);
        currentNode->next->name = name;
        currentNode->next->value = val;
        currentNode->next->next = NULL;
    }
}

void removeLast(node_js **thing) {
    if (*thing == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if ((*thing)->next == NULL) {
        free(*thing);
        *thing = NULL;
        return;
    }

    currentNode = *thing;

    while (currentNode->next->next != NULL) {
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }

    free(currentNode->next);
    currentNode->next = NULL;
}
```

**main.c**

```c
//the problem is on the addLast() inside the while(1), the probelm only occur with items that are
//added when user inputs "add"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

static int numInput;
static char textInput[32];

static char uInput[16];

node_js *list = NULL;

int main() {
     printf("--- Welcome to the program! ---\n>Type 'exit', 'quit' or 'q' to exit\n>Type 'help' for a list of the commands\n\n");

    //make list
    list = (node_js *)malloc(sizeof(node_js));

    list->name = "joe";
    list->value = 10;
    list->next = (node_js *)malloc(sizeof(node_js));

    list->next->name = "james";
    list->next->value = 20;
    list->next->next = NULL;

    addLast(&list, "jane", 30); //here it works fine

    while (1) {
        printf("input: ");
        scanf_s("%s", textInput, sizeof(textInput));

        if (strcmp(textInput, "quit") == 0 || strcmp(textInput, "q") == 0 || strcmp(textInput, "exit") == 0) {
            printf("Bye!");
            free(list);
            exit(1);
        }
        if (strcmp(textInput, "print") == 0) {
            printList(list);
        }
        if (strcmp(textInput, "add") == 0) {
            printf("name: ");
            scanf_s("%s", uInput, sizeof(uInput));/*the problem is on the addLast() inside the while(1), the probelm only occur with items that are added when user inputs "add"*/
            printf("number: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &numInput, sizeof(numInput));

            addLast(&list, uInput, numInput);
            printf("--- added (%s, %d) ---\n", uInput, numInput);   
        }
        if (strcmp(textInput, "remove") == 0) {
            removeLast(&list);
            printf("--- Removed last item of list ---\n");
        }
    }
    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of using `textInput` to scan the users input, I tried making another array just for that. Could not find anything on this, and also tried asking ChatGPT which did not help.

Comment: You're always adding "the address of `uInput`" to the new nodes. All the nodes have the same address, no matter that the contents of that address were different at the time it was added to the linked list. You need to allocate memory and copy from `uInput`.

Comment: Unrelated: remove code from "list.h"; keep only the declarations in the header file, move code to (possibly) "list.c"

Comment: style suggestion. Instead of `(*thing)->name = name;`, do `struct node *t = *thing; t->name = name; `

Comment: @pmg how do i do that? i dont know much on c strings

Comment: This isn't the place for that... but instead of `(*thing)->name = name;` you want `(*thing)->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1); /* check if ok */ strcpy((*thing)->name, name);`. Also, **do not forget to `free((*thing)->name);` once you are finished working with them**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To largely summarize the comments:

```
addLast(&list, uInput, numInput)
```

and in turn,

```
(*thing)->name = name;
```

sets every node's `name` member as the *same* pointer value: a pointer to the first element of the `uInput` array that exists in `main`. The contents of `uInput` are overwritten every time the `add` command is used, and the result is that all nodes in the list share the same string, which is always the most recently input name.

---

`list->name = "joe";`, `list->next->name = "james";`, and `addLast(&list, "jane", 30);` do not share this problem, because each string literal is a pointer to a distinct<sup>1</sup>, statically allocated, read-only character array.

---

Instead, you must create a *copy* of each string, and store a pointer to the copy in each associated node.

This can be done by allocating memory for *the length of the string* in bytes, plus one additional byte for the [null-terminating character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) (`'\0'`).

The general pattern is

```
char *create_copy_of_a_string(const char *a_string)
{
    char *copy = malloc(1 + strlen(a_string));

    if (copy)
        strcpy(copy, a_string);

    return copy;
}
```

On many platforms (e.g., [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html), and in the upcoming [C23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup)), `strdup` is available, which does just this.

Note that with this approach, creating a list by mixing pointers to dynamically allocated strings (`malloc`) and pointers to statically allocated strings (string literals) will create problems when it comes time to `free` the former. The general advice would be to avoid mixing these two types of pointers.

(*`addLast(&list, "jane", 30);` would be fine in the example below, wheres `list->name = "joe";` would lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).*)

---

Alternatively, change the `name` member to an array, and copy the input to it. Beware of [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) with this approach.

---

Other issues include:

The single `free(list);` only frees the memory for the *first* node in the list.

General repetition of code (`addLast` in particular).

Use of `scanf` (`scanf_s`) for user input can lead to frustrating results when something is incorrectly entered, and the input buffer becomes a mess. The general advice is to read entire *lines* of input into a buffer with `fgets`, and then process that data however you want (commonly `sscanf`, `strtol`, `strtok`, etc.). This isn't foolproof, but it does simplify the problem a great deal.

Implementations of functions should be placed in *source* files (`.c`), not *header* files (`.h`).

---

In the cursory example below, the signatures of the library functions (`printList`, `addLast`, `removeLast`) remain unchanged. This does not leave a lot of room for cleanly handling/propagating errors, so error handling is largely remiss. In particular, a robust program should handle the event that `malloc` (`calloc`) returns `NULL`, and avoid dereferencing a null pointer value.

Otherwise, it is refactored a fair amount (simplified for the sake of brevity).

`list.h`:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

typedef struct node {
    char *name;
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node_js;

void printList(node_js *);
void addLast(node_js **, const char *, int);
void removeLast(node_js **);

#endif
```

`list.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "list.h"

void printList(node_js *node)
{
    while (node) {
        printf("<%s> <%d>\n", node->name, node->value);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void addLast(node_js **head, const char *name, const int value)
{
    node_js *node = calloc(1, sizeof *node);

    /* create a copy of the string */
    node->name = malloc(1 + strlen(name));
    strcpy(node->name, name);

    node->value = value;

    if (!*head)
        *head = node;
    else {
        node_js *current = *head;

        while (current->next)
            current = current->next;

        current->next = node;
    }
}

void removeLast(node_js **node)
{
    if (!*node)
        return;

    while ((*node)->next)
        node = &(*node)->next;

    free((*node)->name);
    free(*node);
    *node = NULL;
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

#define match(x, y) (0 == strcmp((x), (y)))

static int read_a_line(char *buf, int len)
{
    if (!fgets(buf, len, stdin))
        return 0;

    /* remove the newline character, if present */
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;

    return 1;
}

static int add_to_list(node_js **list)
{
    char name[256];
    char value[256];

    printf("Name: ");
    if (!read_a_line(name, sizeof name))
        return 0;

    printf("Value: ");
    if (!read_a_line(value, sizeof value))
        return 0;

    /* assume this succeeds */
    addLast(list, name, strtol(value, NULL, 10));
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    node_js *list = NULL;

    puts("------- Welcome to the program! -------");

    while (1) {
        char selection[256];

        printf("Enter a command (quit, print, add, remove): ");

        if (!read_a_line(selection, sizeof selection) || match(selection, "quit"))
            break;

        if (match(selection, "print"))
            printList(list);
        else if (match(selection, "add"))
            add_to_list(&list);
        else if (match(selection, "remove"))
            removeLast(&list);
        else
            printf("Invalid selection <%s>\n", selection);
    }

    while (list) {
        node_js *next = list->next;
        free(list->name);
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }

    puts("Goodbye.");
}
```

In use:

```
------- Welcome to the program! -------
Enter a command (quit, print, add, remove): add
Name: foo
Value: 123
Enter a command (quit, print, add, remove): add
Name: bar
Value: 456
Enter a command (quit, print, add, remove): add
Name: qux
Value: 789
Enter a command (quit, print, add, remove): print
<foo> <123>
<bar> <456>
<qux> <789>
Enter a command (quit, print, add, remove): remove
Enter a command (quit, print, add, remove): print
<foo> <123>
<bar> <456>
Enter a command (quit, print, add, remove): quit
Goodbye.
```

---

<sup>1. String literals of the same *string value* may or may not occupy the same memory (i.e., two **pointers** to string literals are not guaranteed to compare equal, even if equal in terms of content). [Ref.](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7)</sup>

Comment: Quite a comprehensive answer! I wish I could upvote more... (you might want to test and report allocation failures :)